# How to use watchdog and do something in the main thread if a folder is modified?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, watchdog, joblib

I was looking for a watchdog and I found [this](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/) great library. I need to fit a [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn-cluster-dbscan) model if a file is created in a folder. Joblib is used in the scikit-learn's DBSCAN implementation and joblib doesn't allow to use multiprocessing if the DBSCAN running code is not in the main thread. If I use watchdog, DBSCAN code can't run in the main thread. How can I solve this issue? Below you can find the watchdog script and a simple function to test it. When I run the `main_watchdog.py` and add a file in the folder where the watchdog is watching, it runs the `simple_function.py` in the **Thread-1**. In the mean time, `main_watchdog.py` runs in the **MainThread**.

**PS**: **A solution could be starting a subprocess every time calling the `simple_function.py` but I am afraid that this may cause some issues if multiple files created in the watchdog folder. Imagine receiving 10 or 100 or 10000 files at once...**

```
#main_watchdog.py
import time
import logging
import threading
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler
from a_function import simple_function

class Event(LoggingEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        simple_function(x)

    def on_modified(self, event):
        simple_function(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = 1
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    # path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    path = '/path/to/watch/the/folder'
    event_handler = Event()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print(threading.current_thread().name)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

```
#a_function.py
import threading
def simple_function(x):
    x += 1
    print(threading.current_thread().name)
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am to understand this problem correctly, you need you business logic to run in the main thread and the observer to run in the background thread.
This can be easily solved by calling the observer thread in the backgound by using the threading library and then passing the value of those events to your function call by way of `Queues` which are a way of communication between threads.

```
#main_watchdog.py
import time
import logging
import threading
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import LoggingEventHandler
from a_function import simple_function
import sys
from queue import Queue

q = Queue()
x = 1
class Event(LoggingEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        q.put(x)
    def on_modified(self, event):
        q.put(x)

def run_observer():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    # path = '/path/to/watch/the/folder'
    event_handler = Event()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(threading.currentThread().name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    background_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_observer, args=())
    background_thread.daemon = True
    background_thread.start()
    print('Business logic')
    while True:
        val = q.get(True)
        simple_function(val)
```

The other function can remain the same.

Comment: I've tested this and yes, it works just as I wanted. Thank you. But I want to wait if someone else would point out to an error or something.

Comment: sure. let me know if anything breaks.

Comment: btw. I am not familiar with the term "business logic". My question is; is what I am trying to do (as a whole) called 'business logic' or your way of solving this issue called 'business logic'? I'm currently reading and trying to understand it.

Comment: Business logic is whatever you want to throw in there. Your code can run in the loop.